# Obter parâmetro da url via angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Bem, preciso obter um parâmetro da minha *url* assim que minha página é carregada.

[localhost/123456](http://localhost/123456)

O parâmetro seria: ***123456***

Utilizando o $location, obtive a url completa, mas não conseguir obter o parâmetro que preciso para ser carregado no meu *controller*

```
 myApp.controller('Controller', function ($scope, traineeControlService, $location) {

var vm = this;
//getAll();

$scope.numberOfregistrationUser = {};

var searchObj = $location.url();

  console.log(searchObj);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma seria usar o [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute). Através do [`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) pode configurar as rotas do seu site, e com isso extrair os parâmetros das URLs e injectá-los directamente no seu controlador.

Ou seja:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']); // adicione o ngRoute como modulo do seu modulo

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {

    // indica que quando tiver uma URL do tipo http://localhost/[id], que deve utilizar este template e controlador
    $routeProvider.when('/:id', {

        templateUrl: '[caminho para a sua pagina HTML]',
        controller: 'Controller' // nome do seu controlador
    }); 
})

myApp.controller('Controller', function ($scope, traineeControlService, $routeParams) {

    var vm = this;
    //getAll();
    $scope.numberOfregistrationUser = {};
    // var searchObj = $location.url();

    console.log($routeParams.id);
}
```

O objecto [`$routeParams`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) contém todos os parâmetros definidos na URL (note quando a URL e configurada, o uso do `:` para indicar que e um parâmetro que deve ser lido).