# Como pegar parametros URL AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Como pegar parametro da URL com AngularJS. Se alguem tiver algum exemplo eu agradeço.

```js
$scope.pegaCNPJ = function () {
        var cnpjs = $("#prospectCNPJ").val().replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
        $.post('models/verificaCliente.php', {prospectCNPJ: cnpjs}, function (retorno) {
            console.log(retorno);
            $scope.dados = retorno;
            if (retorno.length > 0) {
                $('#processando').show();
                $timeout(function () {
                    $state.go('cadOportunidade', {id: retorno});
                }, 3000);
            } else {
                $http.jsonp("https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/" + cnpjs, {jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'}).then(function (response) {
                    $scope.valor = response;
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

```js
angular.module('App').config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); // by default '!'
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboardAdmin.php',
            controller: 'AppCtrl',
            resolve: {
                'title': ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
                    $rootScope.title = 'Home';
                }],
            }
        })
        .state('dashboardAdmin', {
            url: '/dashboardAdmin',
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboardAdmin.php',
            controller: 'AppCtrl',
            resolve: {
                'title': ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
                    $rootScope.title = 'Dashboard';
                }],
            }
        })
        .state('cadProspect', {
            url: '/cadProspect',
            templateUrl: 'views/cadProspect.php',
            controller: 'AppCtrl',
            resolve: {
                'title': ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
                    $rootScope.title = 'Cadastro Prospect';
                }],
            }
        })

        .state('cadOportunidade', {
            url: '/cadOportunidade/:id',
            templateUrl: 'views/cadOportunidade.php',
            controller: 'AppCtrl',
            resolve: {
                'title': ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
                    $rootScope.title = 'Cadastro Oportunidade';
                }],
            }
        })
});
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRRwH.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRRwH.jpg)

Comment: Veja se lhe ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274553/obter-par%C3%A2metro-da-url-via-angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usando `$stateProvider`, ficaria assim:

```
$stateProvider.state('/viewPage/:param1/:param2', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html',
    controller: 'MyCtrl'
    ...
});
```

e seu controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','$routeParams', function($scope,$stateParams, $state) {
    var param1 = $state.param1;
    var param1 = $state.param2;
}]);
```

Comment: @Herbert de Lima, consegui passar os parametros para outra página. Estou passando o ID e o nome do cliente, mas a url está aparecendo assim http://localhost/prospect/app/#/cadOportunidade/1/GF%20VIEIRA%20E%20CIA%20LTDA, depois do ID aparece o nome da empresa na url, sabe como posso resolver isso.

Comment: basta montar da forma que você quer que fique a url: `dominio.com.br/usuairo/detalhes` ou `dominio.com.br/usuario?filtros=idade,sobrenome` seria `.state(/usuario?filtros.:*)` você acessando por `$state.filtros` sera um array com todos os parametros, não testei aqui, mas se não me engano é assim